# SQL Query to print columns instances in a new column

Tags: sql

I don't know how to explain but i need a query to take this table:

[Columns in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPMbi.png)

and print it like this:

[Column to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tx7f.png)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
SELECT a1 as a
FROM silly_table
UNION ALL
SELECT a2 as a
FROM silly_table
UNION ALL
SELECT a3 as a
FROM silly_table
ORDER BY 1
```